# How to check in Anaconda prompt the version of my py2neo library installed in my virtual environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, py2neo

Is there a way to check via Anaconda prompt which is the version of my py2neo library installed in my virtual environment?

The only ways I found to do it is to

manually search into the results of `pip freeze`.

Use the python shell with

```
python
```

and then

```
>>>import py2neo
>>>py2neo.__version__
```

> '2020.1.1'

Comment: `conda list -n envname py2neo`

Comment: It responds with EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment. In fact my virtual environment is a python one.

Comment: _In fact my virtual environment is a python one._ What do you mean? Are you not using Conda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type:

```
conda list -n environment_name
```

It will only list packages on that virtual environment and you'll see version of all packages.

If your package is installed using pip instead of conda, you can use:

```
pip list
```

To only show all the information of one package (installed using pip), type:

```
pip show package_name
```

Comment: Some kind of error appears?
One more thing, if you installed your package with pip, you can try and use `pip list`

Comment: conda list returns an empty list. pip list works, but I have to search it manually.. thanks

Comment: Ok, to only show that specific package, type: `pip show package_name`